# Explode function returns result twice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to php programming , i don't know is this code correct or not.I refer some where and wrote this code. Here i am using an explode function and its result is returning twice.

```
<?php
$SlNo = 1;
foreach ($record as $r2) { // this is for fetching all form first table
    ?>
                    <?php
    foreach ($selectdata as $r) { // this is to fetch imploded record from second table
        $test = $r->package_id;
    }

    $explode = explode(',', $test);

    foreach ($explode as $r1) {
        // echo $r1. "<br/>";

        if ($r2->package_name == $r1) {

            ?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>" type="checkbox"
            name="package[]" value="<?php  echo $r1; ?>" checked="checked"> <label
            for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>"> <?php  echo $r1; ?></label>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
        } else {
            ?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>" type="checkbox"
            name="package[]" value="<?php  echo $r2->package_name; ?>"> <label
            for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>"> <?php  echo $r2->package_name; ?></label>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is how i get my result 
[image: issue now]

Comment: what is your expected output? what is the error showing now?

Comment: i want to show the result only once

Comment: add `print_r($explode);` this to next line of `$explode =  explode(',', $test);` and check the values

Comment: what is '$record' and '$selectdata'? what are the rows inside?

Comment: $record is to get all the values from first table and $selectdata is to get the imploded data from db

Comment: what is the value stored in '$selectdata'. give an example

Comment: honeymoon package,students package,kerala ayurveda package

Comment: If echo $selectdata; will get the above values?

Comment: yes it shows the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above communication, u said `$selectdata` as the package value. explode it before the for loop.

```html
<?php 

foreach($selectdata as $r)
{
$t= $r->package_id; 
}

$explode =  explode(',',$t);

$SlNo=1;
foreach ($record as $r2)
{    // this is for fetching all  form first table

//echo $r1. "<br/>";

if(in_array($r2->package_name, $explode))
{

?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>" type="checkbox" name="package[]" value="<?php  foreach ($explode as $e){ echo $e; }?>" checked="checked">
    <label for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>"> <?php echo $r2->package_name; ?></label>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>" type="checkbox" name="package[]" value="<?php  echo $r2->package_name; ?>">
    <label for="checkbox<?php echo $SlNo++ ; ?>"> <?php  echo $r2->package_name; ?></label>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @SoorajS Saw ur edit above; the $selectdata is looping unnecessarily, the variable $t get last value of $selectdata only. also $selectdata has single string value, iteration not required.

Comment: without using that looping it is not possible to get the imploded value.

Comment: The looping never used any concatenate operator. If have multiple rows inside it will take last row only.

Comment: Also try replace foreach($selectdata){} with $t= $selectdata->package_id;

Comment: yes i done that but it shows "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: whats the key value pair of $selectdata

Comment: $selectdata has a collection of records from database